# Why is my proof that $\mathbb R$ is disconnected wrong?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, connectedness

The definition of connectedness in my notes is:
A topological space $X$ is connected if there does not exist a pair of non empty subsets $U$, $V$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $U\cup V=X$.

However if I have the subsets $(-\infty,0]$ and $(0,\infty)$ then these are disjoint and cover $\mathbb R$ and hence $\mathbb R$ is disconnected.

However $\mathbb R$ is clearly connected.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: *Open sets*. You're missing the point 'open sets'.

Comment: Yes thank you, that would fix it

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With your definition, *every* space $X$ with at least two points would be disconnected: just take a point $x\in X$ and consider $X=\{x\}\cup(X\setminus\{x\})$.

The definition requires $U$ and $V$ to be disjoint nonempty ***open*** sets such that $U\cup V=X$.

The set $(-\infty,0]$ is not open.

Answer (score 0):

The subsets that you take are wrong because $(-\infty ,0]$ contains a accumulation point of $(0,\infty)$.